# MySQL - Selecting first 100 records from each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing an application wherein I need to show data around the first 100 records (basically sales orders) for each month. The table structure looks like this:-

```
order_id (primary-key) | order_name | order_amount | order_time
```

The problem is that the table can have upto 10 years (120 months) of data, not necessarily sorted in any fashion with each month having anywhere between 0 to 5000 orders. How should I go about writing a query that LIMITs to returning first 100 orders of every month (in an efficient manner)?

Comment: If recursive CTE is possible then you could possibly use that with the `LIMIT` clause to limit the query to 100 per month.

Comment: You can  find lot of examples if you search "select top N row per group". If you can create a sqlfiddle with minimum sample data like 2 months and 3 rows per month and fetch top 2 rows per month, people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in MySQL, but it is not as simple as adding a LIMIT clause. [Here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) is an article that explains the problem in detail.

Comment: James, thanks for the pointer. In my case though, the purchase orders can't necessarily be numbered (1 to n) as they aren't entered in that fashion. Actually, only orders are entered only when completed, but the timestamp on them is that of when the order was initiated. So numbering rows won't help much i guess.